# Error 500 laravel production and "Class view does not exist in /src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:833" nginx log error

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, ubuntu-16.04, laravel-8

I am facing a problem of ***error 500*** in my laravel production website.

My application used to work well before a `composer update` command I ran from ssh to ubuntu server. I used to use *forge* for deployment and after deploying via ssh I faced this issue.

when I check nginx error logs I get this error:

```html
2021/03/31 09:40:54 [error] 29517#29517: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ReflectionException: Class view does not exist in /home/forge/my_site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:833
Stack trace:
#0 /home/forge/my_site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(833): ReflectionClass->__construct('view')
#1 /home/forge/my_site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(714): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('view')
#2 /home/forge/my_site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(841): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('view', Array, true)
#3 /home/forge/my_site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(652): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->resolve('view', Array)
#4 /home/forge/my_site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(826): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('view', Array)
#5 /home/forge/www.itutori...
PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ReflectionException: Class view does not exist in /home/forge/my_site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:833
Stack trace:
#0 /home/forge/www.itutorialist.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(833): ReflectionClass->__construct('view')
#1 /home/forge/my_site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(714): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('view')
#2 /home/forge/my_site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(841): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('view', Array, true)
#3 /home/forge/my_site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(652): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->resolve('view', Array)
#4 /home/forge/my_site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(826): Illuminate\C
```

in some of my searches I found maybe the issu is from app.php, so this is my config/app.php file :

```html
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Environment
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This value determines the "environment" your application is currently
    | running in. This may determine how you prefer to configure various
    | services your application utilizes. Set this in your ".env" file.
    |
    */

    'env' => env('APP_ENV', 'production'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Debug Mode
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When your application is in debug mode, detailed error messages with
    | stack traces will be shown on every error that occurs within your
    | application. If disabled, a simple generic error page is shown.
    |
    */

    'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', false),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application URL
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This URL is used by the console to properly generate URLs when using
    | the Artisan command line tool. You should set this to the root of
    | your application so that it is used when running Artisan tasks.
    |
    */

    'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Timezone
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the default timezone for your application, which
    | will be used by the PHP date and date-time functions. We have gone
    | ahead and set this to a sensible default for you out of the box.
    |
    */

    'timezone' => 'UTC',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Locale Configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The application locale determines the default locale that will be used
    | by the translation service provider. You are free to set this value
    | to any of the locales which will be supported by the application.
    |
    */

    'locale' => 'en',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Fallback Locale
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The fallback locale determines the locale to use when the current one
    | is not available. You may change the value to correspond to any of
    | the language folders that are provided through your application.
    |
    */

    'fallback_locale' => 'en',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Encryption Key
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This key is used by the Illuminate encrypter service and should be set
    | to a random, 32 character string, otherwise these encrypted strings
    | will not be safe. Please do this before deploying an application!
    |
    */

    'key' => env('APP_KEY'),

    'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Autoloaded Service Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The service providers listed here will be automatically loaded on the
    | request to your application. Feel free to add your own services to
    | this array to grant expanded functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    'providers' => [

        /*
         * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
         */
        Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Pipeline\PipelineServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,

        Illuminate\Notifications\NotificationServiceProvider::class,

        /*
         * Application Service Providers...
         */
        App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,
        //Custom Service Providers...
        App\Providers\AccessIdServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\CategoryServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\ChannelConfigServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\UserListServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\GeneralInfoServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\MessageServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\TutorialServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\FileServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\UserServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\RatingServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\ReportServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\TutorialProviderServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\TutorialReviewServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\TutorialReviewCommentServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\TutorialReviewLikeServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\ITutorialistRedirectorServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\SaveTextsServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\FollowServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\ThreadServiceProvider::class,

        //buzz laravel google captcha
        Buzz\LaravelGoogleCaptcha\CaptchaServiceProvider::class,

        //Laravel Scout
        Laravel\Scout\ScoutServiceProvider::class,

        //artesaos seotools
        Artesaos\SEOTools\Providers\SEOToolsServiceProvider::class,

        //Bugsnag
        Bugsnag\BugsnagLaravel\BugsnagServiceProvider::class,

        //Laravel Backup
        Spatie\Backup\BackupServiceProvider::class,

        //Laravelium/laravel-sitemap
        Laravelium\Sitemap\SitemapServiceProvider::class,

        //jenssegers
        Jenssegers\Agent\AgentServiceProvider::class,

        //laravel socialite
        Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteServiceProvider::class,

        //html min
        HTMLMin\HTMLMin\HTMLMinServiceProvider::class,

        //redirect
        Spatie\MissingPageRedirector\MissingPageRedirectorServiceProvider::class,

        //image intervention
        Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider::class,

        //laravel Purifier
        Mews\Purifier\PurifierServiceProvider::class,

        //laravel image optimizer
        Spatie\LaravelImageOptimizer\ImageOptimizerServiceProvider::class,

        //tinker
        Laravel\Tinker\TinkerServiceProvider::class,

        //tracker
        PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\ServiceProvider::class,


    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Class Aliases
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This array of class aliases will be registered when this application
    | is started. However, feel free to register as many as you wish as
    | the aliases are "lazy" loaded so they don't hinder performance.
    |
    */

    'aliases' => [

        'App' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::class,
        'Arr' => Illuminate\Support\Arr::class,
        'Artisan' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::class,
        'Auth' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::class,
        'Blade' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade::class,
        'Broadcast' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Broadcast::class,
        'Bus' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Bus::class,
        'Cache' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache::class,
        'Captcha' => Buzz\LaravelGoogleCaptcha\Captcha::class,
        'Carbon' => Carbon\Carbon::class,
        'Config' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config::class,
        'Cookie' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie::class,
        'Crypt' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt::class,
        'DB' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::class,
        'Eloquent' => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::class,
        'Event' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event::class,
        'File' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::class,
        'Gate' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate::class,
        'Hash' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash::class,
        'Http' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http::class,
        'Lang' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang::class,
        'Log' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::class,
        'Mail' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail::class,
        'Password' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password::class,
        'Queue' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue::class,
        'Redirect' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect::class,
        'Redis' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis::class,
        'Request' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::class,
        'Response' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::class,
        'Route' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::class,
        'Schema' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema::class,
        'Session' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::class,
        'Storage' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::class,
        'URL' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL::class,
        'Validator' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::class,
        'View' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\View::class,
        'SEO' => Artesaos\SEOTools\Facades\SEOTools::class,
        'Bugsnag' => Bugsnag\BugsnagLaravel\Facades\Bugsnag::class,
        'Agent' => Jenssegers\Agent\Facades\Agent::class,
        'Socialite' => Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite::class,
        'Image' => Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::class,
        'Purifier' => Mews\Purifier\Facades\Purifier::class,
        'ImageOptimizer' => Spatie\LaravelImageOptimizer\Facades\ImageOptimizer::class,
        'HTMLMin' => HTMLMin\HTMLMin\Facades\HTMLMin::class,
        'Tracker' => PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Facade::class,
    ],

];
```

I am using

- Laravel 8
- PHP 7.4.16 (cli)
- Ubuntu 16.04.1

The application works well in **local environment** and worked before the composer update from ssh.

**.env file** also exists and details are set.

I have done these steps but none of them helped solving the issue:

1. changing permissions of folders from ssh going te way of this answer:
   https://stackoverflow.com/a/37266353/4985607
2. running these command :

```
    php artisan view:clear
    php artisan cache:clear
    php artisan config:clear
    php artisan config:cache
    composer uodate
    composer dump-autoload
    php artisan optimize
```

3. deleting vendor folder and run `composer install`
4. deleting bootstrap/cache inside files and rerun `composer update`

can any one help me solving this problem please?

Comment: Please share more details. Running `composer update` on a production system is always a bad idea

Comment: @NicoHaase Thanks for reply. what other details should I add?  yea I wanted to deploy on ssh and not the forge. now what should I do? any idea?

Comment: Are you sure you have  run composer install on server?
Check if that View Class  exist on given namespace.

Comment: Why not restore the application to the latest working configuration (from your version control system), run the update again (on your local system) and check whatever has changed?

Comment: @Rudra yes I did composer install via ssh to my server. and also composer update

Comment: @NicoHaase how should I do composer update from local and not from server while my vendor folder should be in .gitignore? does the changes take place after pulling?

Comment: Can you revert back composer.json which was there before you run composer update? and rerun composer install ?

Comment: What was the output of the composer install and composer update commands? Any errors or warnings?

Comment: @JamesClarkDeveloper no error but this warning only: Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details

Comment: I don't get the question. Simply run `composer update` on your local system - that's how you run an update, that's how you already did it. "does the changes take place after pulling" - yeah, of course. You should have `composer.lock` under version control and run `composer install` on your production system (or even better: before deploying your code to the production system, such that you don't have to install Composer there)

Comment: If it is working on your local machine.you can try  to delete composer.json, composer.lock and vendor from server, copy your local composer.json to server and run composer install.

Comment: @NicoHaase okay so I restore my application to previous version then from local running composer update then after pulling the changes to production I have to run composer install from production. is it this? I'll try this.

Comment: @Rudra no, one should **never** run `composer install` on a production system where `composer.lock` is missing

Comment: @NicoHaase I did composer update in local area and then I pushed composer.lock to the git and pulled it. in production I did run composer install, but again the problem exists. only after installing packages I get lots of suggestions like this: symfony/routing suggests installing doctrine/annotations (For using the annotation loader)
symfony/routing suggests installing symfony/config (For using the all-in-one router or any loader)
symfony/routing suggests installing symfony/expression-language (For using expression matching)
what should I do now?

Comment: I can't tell you - these suggestions have not been part of your initial question. Also, these are **suggestions** and there's nothing bad in ignoring them

Comment: @NicoHaase I mean about the problem which still exists in my application. error 500 still exists in my project. what to do about it

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue and found issue in *config* folder > constants file
I was wrote "asset('/')" function in config file, we can't write such functions in config.

Hope this answer  will some one who stuck like this errors.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same error, I found that I mistakenly changed APP_LOG from errorlog to debug
APP_LOG=errorlog
To
APP_LOG=debug
(I was trying to do something not related to this issue)

Once I changed it back to errorlog, and ran php artisan config:cache, it worked again.